# Macbook 09' 13inch OS cant find drive i just installed

Tags: install

i recently installed a 500gb hard drive in an 09 macbook pro because the previous hard drive had went bad and i'm trying to install the OS.X Snow Leopard. Couldnt install it because it couldnt find the Hard drive when it asked choose drive to install...the 500gb hard drive is brand new. What do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to partition the drive.  In the Snow Leopard installer, go to the Utilities menu, and start Disk Utility.  From there, you can partition your new drive, and then you can install the OS onto it.

Comment: I tried to partition like you suggested..and it said piosx error cannot allocate memory.. What should I do now?

Comment: I think you mean "posix".  I googled it and it looks like it is an issue with the connecting cable?  You might try disconnecting and reconnecting to be sure everything is correct. Other than that, I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions...

Comment: I appreciate the help bro.